# Death Psychology

Tags: psychology, death

1. Why do we sympathize in general when we see something or someone dying even if we personally don't know it/them?
2. Is there any species which sympathize with the death of its own species?
3. Is there any species which sympathize with the death of other species?

Comment: It's considered a requisite on biology.se that at least some research is carried out and presented with your question. Otherwise it will be closed as *homework*. The [site tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help)  provide guidance on how to use this site. Please take a few minutes to read about the kind of questions which are on topic here.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic in biology unless more technical details are included. I think CogSci.SE would be [suitable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96813/where-can-i-ask-the-question-about-psychology) for this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have submitted a migration request

Comment: @CRags - migration is often performed only with rockstar questions. As you haven't had any upvotes whatsoever I suggest cross posting.

Comment: @ChrisStronks do I close the question here?

Comment: @CRags - nope, just leave it as is, or close it if you wish of course